# How to get schema name from DataSource or Connection object

Tags: jdbc, db2, datasource, jndi

I want to get the schema name from my DataSource or Connection object so that it can be used in my SQL queries dynamically. I'm using DB2 and there is no implementation of connection.getSchema() in DB2 driver.

I'm using DataSource to get connection. Since connection.getSchema() is not working, I tried another approach as given below

```
connection.getMetaData().getURL()
```

But this is returning connection URL without schema information like below:

```
jdbc:db2://servername:1446/DBName
```

But i have given schema information in the URL while creating the datasource in embeddable Container.

```
jdbc:db2://servername:1446/DBName:currentSchema=mySchema
```

I need to get schema name to use it in query. Somebody knows how to get schema name.

Answer (score 0):

Try the SQL statement

```
values current schema
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Db2BaseDataSource](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021822.html) has a property currentSchema, along with a getter and a setter.
There's also a property called `user` .

```
setter: 

db2ds.setCurrentSchema("fred");

getter:

String x = db2ds.getCurrentSchema() ;
```

Comment: I have injected DataSource resource using DI.      @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/testDB")
 private DataSource dataSource; And the implementation is not the type of Db2BaseDataSource or its sub type. Its of com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource

Comment: @Rajeesh  then your question was incorrect without that fact, so you should update your question. Check if there's a method in the com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.* classes that give access to the native connection, and its properties.

Comment: I mentioned it in the Question that Im using embeddable container, where resource adapter classes are using as a wrapper. BTW, there is no classes and method available to give schema. I explored it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you retrieve a valid connection object, Use `connection.getCatalog()`